# Is there a way to extract timezone_abbr from snowflake database?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

ORACLE Query: select extract(timezone_abbr FROM sysdate at TIME zone 'America/New_York') from dual;

Is there any way to get the timezone_abbr in snowflake database, similar to what we are doing in ORACLE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no direct way to extract timezone abbreviation from snowflake similar to Oracle.
But we can find it by calculating the difference between the 2 time zones.

```
SELECT cast(your_column AS TIMESTAMP) yourtimecolumn
    ,decode(
        extract(
           hour FROM 
            convert_timezone('America/New_York', 'UTC', 
              cast(your_column AS TIMESTAMP)
            )
          ) - 
      extract(hour FROM cast(your_column AS TIMESTAMP)
      ), 
  4, 'EDT', -20, 'EDT', 5, 'EST', -19, 'EST') timezone
FROM your_table
WHERE cast(your_column AS TIMESTAMP) IS NOT NULL 
limit 100
```

The above query assumes your timestamp is in America/Newyork and it tries to convert it to UTC since that is the global time zone.

After the conversion, as the usual way if the difference is 4 then the timezone is in EDT and if the difference is 5 then the timezone is in EST.

**EDIT: To include the time that exceeds a day due to the UTC conversion**

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, Snowflake doesn't store the timezone information - it only stores the offset from UTC.

So the answer from arunb2w works. You can make it a bit simpler by using `extract` with `tzh` and `tzm` components.